# Data types np.dtype(np.int32) vs np.int32 in NumPy 1.20

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Consider this use case:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.int32
b = np.dtype(a)

print(a == b)
# True

A = np.array([1, 2], dtype=a)
B = np.array([1, 2], dtype=b)

print(A == B)
# [True True]

print(a is b)
# False
```

Whereas the arrays in this case are equal to each other, the data types are not identical.
What is the difference between `np.dtype(np.int32)` and `np.int32`?

My question can be extended to the other data types, not just `np.int32`.

Comment: V 1.20 release notes talks about a change in this kind of testing.  You need to use `isinstance` testing.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html#isinstance-dtype-np-dtype-and-not-type-dtype-is-not-np-dtype

Comment: Technically `np.int32` is a function, not an instance of `np.dtype`.

Comment: Can I use `np.dtype(np.int32)` and `np.int32` interchangeably?

Comment: For what purpose?  This 1.20 change just applies to testing.  I don't think there's any change when specifying dtype when creating arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Here it clearly says: "Note that the scalar types are not dtype objects, even though they can be used in place of one whenever a data type specification is needed in NumPy."

So we can use np.int32, which is a scalar type, interchangeably with np.dtype(np.int32) for the data type specification. Both will be eventually evaluated to dtype('int32')
You can also see this as following.

```
   np.result_type(A)
    #dtype('int32')
   np.result_type(B)
    #dtype('int32')
```

also:

```
    np.result_type(a)
    #dtype('int32')
    np.result_type(b)
    #dtype('int32')
```